# Crystal Reports Error: Column '' does not belong to table Command

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I recently upgraded Crystal Reports for Visual Studio from VS 2008  to latest version. I am able to see my old reports in the preview pane but when I run the report in my Windows application it gives my error that column '' does not belong to table Command, where Command is the SQL query I have given to the report. This is happening for every report and not just any report. I also tried a generic report without any input parameters. It still gave me same error.

I am using MS Access database and Windows Forms client application.